# R markdown knit to pdf is not keeping the order

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr

I have the following R markdown document and it changes the order of the document when I knit to pdf with pdf latex (invert the chunk and text order, nothing about images):
(output below)

````
    ---
title: |
  | Title
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
always_allow_html: 'true'
---


```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = 'H' )
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

#### Paquetes que vamos a usar en alguno de los ejercicios:

```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(rio)
library(rknn)
library(kknn)
```

## 0. Análisis exploratorio y transformación de los datos

#### Primero cargamos el archivo con los datos

```{r warning=FALSE}
setwd("P:/MDS/AEM/Entrega 2") # Mi Working directory, cambiar para que funcione
dataset_raw <- import("khantrainadd.csv")
dataset_raw$V1 <- NULL # esta columna con el indice no nos interesa
head(dataset_raw)[,1:5]
table(dataset_raw$class) # Mi variable objetivo
dim(dataset_raw)
```
````

Output screenshot

[image]

as you can see, the chunk is over the text. I have tried several things and couldn't find a solution. Any suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps the reason is that you are creating a table in latex. The position of table in latex is usually at the end or starting of the page, unless forced to hold position. You can try `kable` and use `HOLD_position = T` in `kable_styling`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Just to check that, I have removed all tables in the documents and still the output order is the same...

Comment: Welcome to SO, @AleCampoy. What about `### Primero cargamos el archivo con los datos`?

Comment: Indeed it work!, thank you very much. But couldn't understand the reason at all...